# Defind return object model

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using springfox and springboot to create MVC API.

I have a common response class/pojo, which is use to return the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {},
  "status": "string"
}
```

The data field I defined it as Object:

```
private Object data;
```

So I can assign any Object into the data, before response.

My question is how to show what object should return at Swagger?

For example the below will tell it return Dog as the data:

**GET /api/dog:**

```
{
   "data": Dog {},
   "status": "string"
}
```

the below will tell it return Dog as the data:

**GET /api/cat:**

```
{
   "data": CAT {},
   "status": "string"
}
```

Maybe I use generics T?